# How does a variable declaration work as a function?

Tags: javascript

the following script uses a Greensock utility to map values and the script is set within a resize function. In the function I don't understand how  `getPercent` is used as if it was called as a function bu it is declared as a variable

```
const maxRot = 10;
const setRot = gsap.quickSetter("h1", "rotationY", "deg");

gsap.set("h1", {transformOrigin: "center center"});

let getPercent;
function resize() {
  getPercent = gsap.utils.mapRange(0, innerWidth, -1, 1);
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  const percent = getPercent(e.pageX);
  setRot(percent * maxRot);
});

window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
resize();
```

But the syntax of `getPercent` seems to be written as a variable

```
getPercent= gsap.utils.mapRange(0,innerWidth, -1, 1)
```

but then its called as a function

```
const percent= getPercent(e.pageX)
```

I don't  understand why getPercent is not written as for example

```
function getPercent(value){
return gsap.util.mapRange(0,innerWidth,-1,1,value)
}
```

I hope this makes sense

Comment: That means `gsap.utils.mapRange` *returns a function*, so `getPercent` is a function.

Comment: JS is bit weird as compare to other languages, we can store function in a variable and return a function from any other function instead of value if we want. And with reference of variable , we can call it anytime.

Comment: @Abhinav Define “weird”. That’s pretty normal in many languages in some form or another.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar Please name one programming language that can't store a function in a variable. I know there exist some ancient language that don't support it but all modern languages I know support it.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Which modern programming language supports use of functions like JS?

Comment: @Rahul C, C++, Python, PHP, Matlab, Go, Java and Haskell support it for sure. A programming language couldn't survive without it. Generic programming and algorithms are important and you want  to pass a function as argument to a sort function or filter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A programming language is said to have First-class functions when functions in that language are treated like any other variable. For example, in such a language, a function can be passed as an argument to other functions, can be **returned** by another function, and can be assigned as a value to a variable.

You can do

```js
let sayHello = function() {
   return function() {
      console.log("Hello!");
   }
}
const myFunc = sayHello();
myFunc();
```

There might be the similar implementation of `mapRange`.

You should read docs or implementation of `mapRange`.